# Lombok Builder with extra validations on Enum

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I have a class like this -

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Testing {

    @NonNull private String id;

    @NonNull private TestEnum test;

    private String message;

}



public enum TestEnum {
    ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA;
}
```

I have a use-case where I need the value of test to be only `ALPHA` or `BETA`. To ensure this is there any annotation that I can use with the builder annotation? The only other way I can think of doing this is writing my own builder implementation? The other way could be to write my own annotation that does that validation but I am not sure if that would work with the Lombok one? Is there a simpler way to do this?

I don't think this scenario applies here - [Lombok builder to check non null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855981/lombok-builder-to-check-non-null-and-not-empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write out the entire builder. Just write the `test` method of the builder, and add your own validation:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Testing {

    @NonNull private String id;

    @NonNull
    private TestEnum test;

    private String message;

    public static class TestingBuilder {
        public TestingBuilder test(@NonNull TestEnum test) {
            if (test != TestEnum.ALPHA && test != TestEnum.BETA) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("test can only be ALPHA or BETA!");
            }
            this.test = test;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the builder class' name and the name of the `test` method should be the same as whatever Lombok would have otherwise generated.

If you do not want *any* instance of `Testing` to be created that has a `test` value of `GAMMA`, not just those instances created using the builder, you should write your own constructor instead:

```
public Testing(@NonNull String id, @NonNull TestEnum test, @NonNull String message) {
    if (test != TestEnum.ALPHA && test != TestEnum.BETA) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("test can only be ALPHA or BETA!");
    }
    this.id = id;
    this.test = test;
    this.message = message;
}
```